# How can people meet again after rebirth?

Tags: rebirth, death, life-after-death

Prince Siddhartha & Princess Yashodhara met in a lot of lives as partners. How are people intended to meet their present life relations in the next life? Is the desire needed to be wished upon?

Comment: [Samajivina Sutta: Living in Tune](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.055.than_en.html) ..."Lord, ever since Nakula's mother as a young girl was brought to me [to be my wife] when I was just a young boy, I am not conscious of being unfaithful to her even in mind, much less in body. We want to see one another not only in the present life but also in the life to come."...

Comment: I edited my answer to include the sutta citation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you both have:

> (1) compatible faith (sama,saddhā),
>
> (2) compatible virtue (sama,silā),
>
> (3) compatible charity (sama,cāgā),
>
> (4) compatible wisdom (sama,pannā).

[Sama,jivi Sutta 1](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/5.1-Samajivi-S-1-a4.55-piya1.pdf)

With the balance of probability, you will be born in the same plane, which increases the chance of meeting again. There is no guarantee through. This will make your current life together effective.

What is desirable is not achieved through wishing or praying, but through action resulting is conducive karma, i.e, convergent, action-based karma from both parties should spontaneously effect reunion:

> they are not to be obtained through prayer (ayacana,hetu) or through wishing (patthana,hetu)

[Pañcaka Iṭṭha Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/47.2-Pancaka-Ittha-S-a5.43-piya.pdf)

> all of them are rooted in diligence, converge on diligence,

[(Hatthi) Pada Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/47.2-Pancaka-Ittha-S-a5.43-piya.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much. May the noble triple gem bless you!